# How to get my definite loop to print one per line

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to process a list of words and return a new list 
    containing only unique word. My definite loop works, however it will only print the words all together, instead of one per line. Can anyone help me out? This is probably a simple question but I am very new to Python. Thank you!

```
uniqueWords = [ ]

for word in allWords:
    if word not in uniqueWords:
        uniqueWords.append(word)
    else:
        uniqueWords.remove(word)

return uniqueWords
```

Comment: Where is the code you use to print the `uniquewords` list?

Comment: The printing is not shown in your code, but I am assuming it is something like `print(myfunction())`.  You could change that to `print("\n".join(myfunction()))`

Comment: Why are you calling `remove()`?  Words that occur an even number of times in `allWords` will not end up being present in `uniqueWords`, but words that occur an odd number of times will do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join`:

```
>>> all_words = ['two', 'two', 'one', 'uno']
>>> print('\n'.join(get_unique_words(all_words)))
one
uno
```

Or plain `for loop`:

```
>>> for word in get_unique_words(all_words):
...     print(word)
... 
one
uno
```

---

However, your method won't work for odd counts:

```
>>> get_unique_words(['three', 'three', 'three'])
['three']
```

If your goal is to get all words that appear exactly once, here's a shorter method that works using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_unique_words(all_words):
    return [word for word, count in Counter(all_words).items() if count == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help, it prints unique words line by line, is what I understood in your question:

```
allWords = ['hola', 'hello', 'distance', 'hello', 'hola', 'yes']

uniqueWords = [ ]

for word in allWords:
    if word not in uniqueWords:
        uniqueWords.append(word)
    else:
        uniqueWords.remove(word)

for i in uniqueWords:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the words is not important I recommend you to create a set to store the unique words:

```
uniqueWords = set(allWords)
```

As you can see running the code below, it can be much faster, but it may depend on the original list of words:

```
import timeit
setup="""
word_list = [str(x) for x in range(1000, 2000)]
allWords = []
for word in word_list:
    allWords.append(word)
    allWords.append(word)
"""
smt1 = "unique = set(allWords)"
smt2 = """
uniqueWords = [ ]

for word in allWords:
    if word not in uniqueWords:
        uniqueWords.append(word)
    else:
        uniqueWords.remove(word)
"""
print("SET:", timeit.timeit(smt1, setup, number=1000))
print("LOOP:", timeit.timeit(smt2, setup, number=1000))
```

OUTPUT:

SET: 0.03147706200002176

LOOP: 0.12346845000001849

Answer (score 0):

maybe this fits your idea:

```
allWords=['hola', 'hello', 'distance', 'hello', 'hola', 'yes']
uniqueWords=dict()
for word in allWords:
  if word not in uniqueWords:
    uniqueWords.update({word:1})
  else:
    uniqueWords[word]+=1
for k, v in uniqueWords.items():
  if v==1:
    print(k)
```

Prints:

```
distance
yes
```